# Presenting raw hazard ratios, not log(hazard ratio), in forest plot for meta-analysis using metafor

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard, forest-plot, metafor

I'm trying to perform a meta-analysis in R with metafor of trials for which the hazard ratios(HR) and 95% CI are available as outcomes.

I am aware that I have to use log(HR) for calculation, but I want to create a forest plot with raw HR, not log(HR).

However, when I write a code like this, only log(HR) are presented.
(of course it does, because I provided log(HR)… but I want to change them back to raw HR when plotting!)

```
    library('metafor')
study <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

HR <- c(1.02, 0.87, 0.74)
lower.HR <- c(0.89, 0.78, 0.58)
upper.HR <- c(1.17, 0.97, 0.95)

yi <- log(HR)
sei <- (log(upper.HR) - log(lower.HR))/1.96*2

dat <- data.frame(yi=yi, sei=sei)

rma.result <- rma(yi=yi,
                   sei=sei,
                   slab=study,
                   data=dat,
                   method="REML")

forest(rma.result)
```

[image]

How can I obtain the forest plot with raw HR (not log(HR), like the one shown below?
Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: transf or atransf (see the help page).

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much for your help, mdewey!